# VBA Function Optional parameters

Tags: vba, function, optional-parameters

I am calling a specific piece of code several times therefore I would like to use optional parameters.
I can write something like:

```
Public Sub main()

strA = "A"

'Calling the function
CalculateMe (strA)

End Sub

Public Sub CalculateMe(strA As String)

    Set rs = DB.OpenRecordset("tbl_A")
    rs.MoveFirst
        Do Until rs.EOF
            If rs.Fields(0) = strA Then
                dblA = rs.fields(2).Value
            End If
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
End Sub
```

How can I change the function to hold more than 1 optional parameters?

Something like:

```
Public Sub main()
strA = "A"
strB = "B"

'Calling the function
CalculateMe (strA, strB)

more code
End Sub

Public Sub CalculateMe(Optional strA As String, Optional strB as String)

    Set rs = DB.OpenRecordset("tbl_A")
    rs.MoveFirst
        Do Until rs.EOF
            If rs.Fields(0).Value = strA And rs.Fields(1).Value = strB Then
                dblA = rs.Fields(2).Value
            End If
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
End Sub
```

Following Pankaj Jaju's advice, I have managed to have it run by changing it to:

```
Public Sub main()
strA = "A"
strB = "B"

'Calling the function
dblA = CalculateMe (strA, strB)

End Sub

Public Function CalculateMe(Optional ByVal strA As String, Optional ByVal strB as String)

Set rs = DB.OpenRecordset("tbl_A")
rs.MoveFirst
    Do Until rs.EOF
        If rs.Fields(0).Value = strA And rs.Fields(1).Value = strB Then
            dblA = rs.Fields(2).Value
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End Sub
```

Now, how can I clear the value of an optional parameter? I will need this for some of the calculations. Something like:

```
Set strA = Nothing
```

Comment: I know this is an old question now, but are you trying to pass an array? Then loop through x items in the array?

Comment: No, I was not; only 2 string variables. I was not familiar with the syntax at the time and Pankaj Jaju help solving that. Changing the function to a subroutine and adding ByVal enabled to perform what I was trying to do. Ignore any other posts/comments; they are only confusing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Change your sub and add `ByVal`

```
Public Sub CalculateMe(Optional ByVal strA As String, Optional ByVal strB As String)
```

Comment: At runtime, how do you tell whether the optional parameter was supplied?

Comment: @ThrowawayAccount3Million - When you call `CalculateMe`, you can choose to specify which argument to pass. For example, if you want to use only `strB`, then call `CalculateMe(,"second")`. Similarly, if you want to use just the first parameter, call `CalculateMe("first")`. If you do not wish to send any parameter, simply call `CalculateMe`.

Comment: Since you did ignore his question, I will ask again ;) At runtime, how do you tell whether the optional parameter was supplied?

Comment: @ThrowawayAccount3Million Use this statement which will compare your parameter with Nothing and do stuff based on that: `If TheParameter Is Nothing Then [statements...]` I did a test-run on it and I used`TheParameter` as a String... so what I guess is that it works with any type of Object.

Comment: @ThrowawayAccount3Million See answer below excerpted from Chip Pearson.

Comment: @MushyPeas See answer below excerpted from Chip Pearson.

Answer (score 12):

```
Public Sub CalculateMe(Optional varA As Variant, Optional varB as Variant)
```

Excerpts from [Chip Pearson's](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/optionalargumentstoprocedures.aspx) excellent explanation:

Rules governing the use of optional parameters:

- The `Optional` keyword must be present to make a parameter optional.
- The data type should be (but need not be, see below) a `Variant` data
  type.
- The optional parameter(s) must be at the end of the parameter
  list.
- The `IsMissing` function will work only with parameters declared
  as `Variant`. It will return `False` when used with any other data type.
- User defined types (UTDs) cannot be optional parameters.

### Example

```
Function Test(L1 As Long, L2 As Long, _
    Optional P1 As Variant, Optional P2 As Variant) As String

    Dim S As String

    If IsMissing(P1) = True Then
        S = "P1 Is Missing."
    Else
        S = "P1 Is Present (P1 = " & CStr(P1) & ")"
    End If

    If IsMissing(P2) = True Then
        S = S & "  " & "P2 Is Missing"
    Else
        S = S & "  " & "P2 Is Present (P2 = " & CStr(P2) & ")"
    End If

    Test = S
End Function
```

Here, both L1 and L2 are required but P1 and P2 are optional. Since both are `Variant` types, we can use `IsMissing` to determine whether the parameter was passed in. `IsMissing` returns `True` if the `Variant` parameter is omitted, or `False` if the `Variant` parameter is included. If the data type of the optional parameter is any data type other than `Variant`, `IsMissing` will return `False`.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `CalculateMe(,strB)` you can use

```
dblA = CalculateMe strB:="B"
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18101580)

Comment: @AnkitBajpai Again, this *is* an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you really mean "optional". In your example, you're listing the args as optional, but you're still passing *both* arguments to the function.

In any case, here you pass *both* arguments:

```
Public Sub main()
strA = "A"
strB = "B"

'Calling the function
dblA = CalculateMe(strA, strB)

more code
End Sub
```

If you want to pass only one of the arguments, then do like:

```
dblA = CalculateMe(, strB)
```

Or:

```
dblA = CalculateMe(strA)
```

Otherwise, if you are always passing both arguments, then it doesn't make sense to have them `Optional`.

Comment: This is correct, I am passing bot arguments but then in another Subroutine calling the same function I will set one of the arguments (the string variable) to = vbNullString

Comment: why would you do that? You could simply pass a nullstring instead: `Calculate("", strB)` etc... Honestly it sounds like you are trying to be too fancy with your approach, without really understanding what you're doing.