# multiple parameters not obligatory

Tags: sql, vba, optional-parameters

I want to write a code with multiple parameters like this :

```
Set param1 = qt.Parameters.Add("City Parameter", xlParamTypeVarChar)
```

and be able to use either one parameter or the second. VBA obliged me to have values for both parameters, but I want to have one obligatory parameter and others optional. What should I add to the code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA Function Optional parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770412/vba-function-optional-parameters)

Comment: Really, just using google would have been faster: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-named-arguments-and-optional-arguments

Comment: You need to make both parameters optional, because `Optional` parameters must appear *at the end of the paremeter list*. That said, asking about a procedure's signature without even sharing what your procedure's signature is, is a little short.

Comment: Wait is this about VBA optional parameters, or query/SQL parameters? If this has nothing to do with SQL, please remove the tag, it makes the post confusing.

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon it seems to be about [Parameters for QueryTables in Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.parameters) which routinely involve SQL.  Of course, I defer to OP.

Comment: @TrevorReid I know it looks like it, but it *reads* like OP merely used the `Parameters.Add` method as an example of a function with multiple optional parameters... I initially understood the question exactly as in the below answer, but now I'm not sure any more.

Comment: I agree it's confusing.  That wasn't my reading at first glance, but hopefully we'll get some help from OP giving OP help :-)

Answer (score 1):

Optional parameters are defined with the term `Optional`

Example:

```
Sub DoStuff(requiredParam as String, Optional optParam as String = "")
```

Adding in the `= ""` is helpful so you can write out the logic depending on whether a value has been passed in. `""` is just an example and you should choose a value that isn't liekly to be passed in.

Comment: You can also leave the ´= something´ and use ´IsMissing()´ to check if a value was passed.

Comment: @L8n `IsMissing` will only work with a `Variant` though

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thanks, good to know, somehow missed that since I usually use it with a variant and ´select case´ for fake overloading.

Comment: Anyway, in this specific case the ´= ""´ should not be necessary as the default value is ´""´ anyway.