# VBA Sub optional parameters with default values

Tags: vba, ms-word, default-value, optional-parameters, word-2016

I am trying to write a VBA sub that allows optional parameters **with default values**. I tried the sample code from [Microsoft Docs - Optional Parameters (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/optional-parameters) but it leads to the sub not showing on list of available subs (i.e. from View Macros).

```
Sub notify(ByVal company As String, Optional ByVal office As String = "QJZ")
    If office = "QJZ" Then
        Debug.WriteLine("office not supplied -- using Headquarters")
        office = "Headquarters"
    End If
    ' Insert code to notify headquarters or specified office.
End Sub
```

The sub declaration I tried, but couldn't get to appear, was:

```
Sub HighlightByFont( _
        Optional ByVal highlightFont As Variant = "", _
        Optional ByVal highlightColor As Variant = "", _
        Optional ByVal highlightText As Variant = "", _
        Optional ByVal matchWildcards As Variant = False, _
        Optional ByVal useGUI As Variant = False, _
        Optional ByVal highlightBold As Variant = False, _
        Optional ByVal highlightItalic As Variant = False)
```

For now, I have had to settle for the below with [IsMissing logic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48200047/7608812):

```
Sub HighlightByFont( _
        Optional ByVal highlightFont As Variant, _
        Optional ByVal highlightColor As Variant, _
        Optional ByVal highlightText As Variant, _
        Optional ByVal matchWildcards As Variant, _
        Optional ByVal useGUI As Variant, _
        Optional ByVal highlightBold As Variant, _
        Optional ByVal highlightItalic As Variant)
```

Is it (still<sup>†</sup>) possible, and if so, how:

1. to set up the parameter declaration?
2. to get it to appear in the View Macros list?

Environment:

- Word 2016 x64
- Windows 10

<sup><sup>†</sup> All references, including SO answers related to VBA optional paramaters are from 2015.</sup>

Comment: Only public subs with no parameters can be seen in the View Macros. Create a sub with no parameters which will be calling this one (once written properly in VBA).

Comment: My current version which has many parameters can be seen in the View Macros list (per OP):
Sub HighlightByFont(Optional ByVal highlightFont As Variant, ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Optional Values Parameter Declaration

Yes, optional parameters with default values still works as late as Word 2016. The [VBA reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/sub-statement) states:

> The arglist argument has the following syntax and parts:
>
> [ Optional ] [ ByVal | ByRef ] [ ParamArray ] varname [ ( ) ] [ As type ] [ = defaultvalue ]
>
> **Optional**  Optional. [Keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/glossary/vbe-glossary#keyword) indicating that an argument is not required. If used, all subsequent arguments in arglist must also be optional and declared by using the **Optional** keyword. **Optional** can't be used for any argument if **ParamArray** is used.
>
> *defaultvalue* Optional. Any constant or constant expression. Valid for **Optional** parameters only. If the type is an **Object**, an explicit default value can only be **Nothing**.

```
Sub OptParam_Test_1()
  'Shows in Macro list
End Sub

Sub OptParam_Test_2(param)
  'Does not show in Macro list
    Debug.Print (param) 'Output for OptParam_Test_2 "hello": hello
End Sub

Sub OptParam_Test_3(Optional param)
  'Shows in Macro list
    Debug.Print (param) 'Output: hello
End Sub

Sub OptParam_Test_4(Optional param As String = "hello")
  'Does not show in Macro list
    Debug.Print (param) 'Output: hello
End Sub

Sub OptParam_Test_5(Optional param As Variant = "hello again")
  'Does not show in Macro list
    Debug.Print (param) 'Output: hello again
End Sub
```

An unexpected interface behavior when declaring parameters with default values is **the sub will stop appearing in the Macros list**.

[image: Note sub examples 1, 3 show. 2, 4, 5 do not.]

This should not be interpreted as the sub having an issue or not being available for use.

- Understandably, it seems to have been a design decision that subs with parameters need to be called from another sub or the Immediate window<sup>1</sup>  and hence don't show in Macros list
  [image]
- Logically, subs with only/all Optional parameters (and without default values<sup>†</sup>) *do show*<sup>2</sup> in the Macros list since invocation, by definition, doesn't require an explicit argument to be supplied
- <sup>†</sup>**Inconsistently**, subs with Optional parameters **and** default values provided *do not* show in the Macros list

### Invocation Options

Two options for invoking subs containing a parameter with default value are:

1. Declare a parameterless calling sub which calls the sub in question. **This calling sub will appear in the Macros list.**

```
    Sub OptParam_Test_4(Optional param As String = "hello")
      'Does not show in Macro list
        Debug.Print (param) 'Output: hello
    End Sub

    Sub OptParam_Test_4_()
      'Shows in Macro list
      OptParam_Test_4
      'Output: hello
    End Sub
```

[image: Caller sub shows in Macros list]

2. Use the Immediate window<sup>1</sup> to call the  sub in question

<sup><sup>1</sup>*Developer - Visual Basic - View - Immediate Window (Ctrl+G)*</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup>contrary to various comments on mulitple SO posts related to this topic</sup>

Answer (score 7):

The link you have provided is to a help page for VB Net and Not VBA.  VBA and VB .Net are similar but have very different use cases.  VBA is the built in scripting language used by Microsoft Office applications.  VB Net is a full bore .Net Language which has its roots in VBA but is not used by Office Application unless you write specific VSTO addins or applications.

Optional arguments in VBA work fine. The VBA version of the code sample you provided above is.

```
Sub notify(ByVal company As String, Optional ByVal office As String = "QJZ")
    If office = "QJZ" Then
        Debug.print "office not supplied -- using Headquarters"
        office = "Headquarters"
    End If
    ' Insert code to notify headquarters or specified office.
End Sub
```

You could also do us all a bit of a favour and learn to use the line break so that

```
Sub HighlightByFont(Optional ByVal highlightFont As Variant = "", Optional ByVal highlightColor As Variant = "", Optional ByVal highlightText As Variant = "", Optional ByVal matchWildcards As Variant = False, Optional ByVal useGUI As Variant = False, Optional ByVal highlightBold As Variant = False, Optional ByVal highlightItalic As Variant = False)
```

is written as

```
Sub HighlightByFont _
( _
    Optional ByVal highlightFont As Variant = "", _
    Optional ByVal highlightColor As Variant = "", _
    Optional ByVal highlightText As Variant = "", _
    Optional ByVal matchWildcards As Variant = False, _
    Optional ByVal useGUI As Variant = False, _
    Optional ByVal highlightBold As Variant = False, _
    Optional ByVal highlightItalic As Variant = False _
)
```

You should also be aware that any optional parameters defined with a default can never be missing and that sometimes IsMissing is the better option to use because its not possible to provide a sensible default.

Comment: I've updated the sample code with line breaks (that's a great tip, thanks.)
It looks like the VB.net and VBA code are nearly the same except for the Debug.WriteLine replaced with Debug.print

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact, that the `Sub` with (all) arguments `Optional` is not visible from Macro List, you can type-in the name of that Sub and .. voila: Run button enables itself and Sub can be Run.